# Turbine engine part identification

Tags: turbine

I picked this up at a yard sale (we call them boot fairs in the UK)

Can anyone identify it ? I'm not good with gas turbines. It is stamped with the serial number 579451A. Its 40 inches in diameter, and the blades/vanes are approx. 12 inches long. There are 51 blades in total. I think it's made by Pratt and Whitney
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help appreciated

Comment: These vanes are probably the vanes of some fan/compressor, Googling the part number without the "A" and vanes gives you links to spare parts providers hinting to second stage stator vanes.